# Loss of Image Information

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tfrecord

When reading a JPEG image from a [TFRecord](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/tfrecord) there seems to be loss of information. Here is an example:

- Original image:
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyKMI.jpg
- Decoded JPEG image (reshaped to 600x600 dims):
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUyoP.jpg

The `tf.data.Dataset` was created using the Keras `image_dataset_from_directory` function and, each image tensor of shape 600x600x3 was encoded to a byte string using the `tf.io.encode_jpeg`:

```
image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image_tensor, dtype=tf.uint8)
image = tf.io.encode_jpeg(image, quality=100)
```

Each TFRecord example was created like this:

```
    # encoded_image is the output of encode_jpeg function
    image_feature = tf.train.Feature(
        bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[
            encoded_image
        ])
    )
    features = tf.train.Features(feature={
        'image': image_feature
    })
    example = tf.train.Example(features=features)
    return example.SerializeToString()
```

And below is the code that loads the TFRecords Dataset, using `tf.image.decode_jpeg` to decode the images back to tensors of shape 600x600x3, and then saves one image to disk using PIL:

```
def read_tfrecord(example):
    tfrecord = {
        "image": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)
    }
    example = tf.io.parse_single_example(example, tfrecord)
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(example['image'], channels=3)
    return image


def read_dataset(dataset_path):
    filenames = tf.io.gfile.glob(dataset_path + '/validation/*.tfrecord')

    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames)
    dataset = dataset.map(read_tfrecord)
    dataset = dataset.repeat()
    dataset = dataset.batch(128)

    for image, label in dataset.take(1):
        Image.fromarray((image[0].numpy())).save('./images/img.jpeg')
```

I have absolutely no clue what is causing this apparent loss of image information so any help would be much appreciated!

Notes:

- I'm using Tensorflow v2.5.0. and Pillow v8.0.1
- Please find the entire code in this Gist: https://gist.github.com/deeDude/c40fa1f14e4fa4b7f2ef149e5a344023

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "loss of image informatIon"? I actually found out tf.io.encode_jpeg and tf.io.decode_jpeg op (using all their defaults), are not necessary symmetrical, meaning if you apply decode follow by encode, the image jpeg can have a different byte count. If you encode_jpeg with high quality=100, you will get more bytes (even sometimes than the original image). So trace through your data and code, and pinpoint where this happens.